# Windows 10 Crash/BSOD using Bridged Network adapter on CentOS VirtualBox

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, centos, bsod

This is quite specific and so hopefully easy to answer. I've just got a new Dell XPS 15 as a desktop replacement.

I've installed CentOS (tried 6 and 7) on VirtualBox, that works fine, but as soon as I set the Network Adapter to Bridged and set inside */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0* the line `ONBOOT=yes` (something I've always done with the many CentOS/VB boxes I've built) windows crashes and I get  BSOD.

When I install CentOS I do get told that the hardware is incompatible:

[image: virtual box centos install unsupported hardware error message]

That error seems to be about the CPU but windows crashes as soon as I type `service network restart`

I don't know where to begin in debugging this, but as it crashes windows it's taking quite a lot of my time to try and find out what is going on.

Any one got any ideas, on where to look if not how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem found to be due to update to Killer Network drivers. Update enabled Killer Bandwidth Control.

From [Virtualbox bug ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16229)

> Solution: Go to control panel, networking, select your network adapter (Local Area Connection), select properties, and uncheck the Killer Bandwidth control.

Comment: Is this on Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm with my XPS 15 9560 with Killer Network adapter